# Drupal Time field for hour:minute:second.tenth of a second

Tags: entities, datetime

Is there a drupal field type to represent time for athletics sports events. e.g. for 100m sprint: 10.42 seconds but for 800m 1:40.89 (1 minute, 40.89 seconds)
In the format : hour:minute:second.tenth of a second

Comment: I created a project to do the same thing. It's currently in the review process and as soon as it's been approved, I'll send you the link.

Comment: The module Robbert referred to is still a sandbox available from https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/robbertv/2158841, but hasn't been thoroughly reviewed or promoted to a full module yet.  I still haven't been able to find a good solution for this.

Comment: I finally got around to getting my sandboxed project promoted to a full project:  https://www.drupal.org/project/racetime

Answer (score 1):

No time field will give you what you are looking for. They all work with Unix time, which is defined as 'the number of seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970'. The maximum granularity you will see is one second.

If you wish to record this information to one one-hundredth of a second, you will need to define the field and its formatting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this module does what you need. But http://drupal.org/project/cck_time may work if it allows you to create a format using PHP. There is also

- http://drupal.org/project/time_entry

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this module [HMS Field](http://drupal.org/project/hms_field)

> Displays a integer formatted as Hours, Minutes or Seconds.
>   The field stores values as integer. Both input and output can be formatted as Hours, Minutes and/or Seconds. Alter functions provides developers a way to add their own format.

Comment: This doesn't support tenth of seconds as required by the OP

Answer (score -1):

This is currently being developed too: https://www.drupal.org/project/timeperiod