# Using Date Popup widget with custom format Date field

Tags: datetime

I need to save a date in a very specific format: (`2013-03-09\T17:01:34.1\Z` to be precise).

I also need to allow users to edit this date after it's been saved.

I want to use the Date Popup submodule of [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) to allow users to enter dates. However, it doesn't seem to support custom formats. When I enable Date Popup, I see that I lose seconds granularity, and I can no longer use custom formats at all.

Is there a way to use custom formats with Date Popup? If not, is there a recommended way of adding a popup calendar to my date field in a way that will generate dates in my custom format? Does anyone know why the developer of Date made Date Popup incompatible with custom formats?

Comment: Unix time has a maximum granularity of i sec. Already covered [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64021/drupal-time-field-for-hourminutesecond-tenth-of-a-second/64145#64145).

Comment: I'm not asking about tenths of seconds. One second is all the granularity I need. Date Popup's minimum supported granularity seems to be one minute. Also, Unix timestamp is not the only date storage format that Date module offers.

Comment: It was the _:34.1_ that caused my comment. You should open an issue for this on D.O.

Comment: The dot is just a delimiter. The 1 represents daylight savings time (`I` in PHP's date format code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in another comment, you should set "#date_format". You should however not set it in hook_form_alter(), but rather in hook_date_combo_process_alter(). Ie:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_date_combo_process_alter().
 *
 * Force 'd.m.Y' date format
 */
function mymodule_date_combo_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['value']['#date_format'] = 'd.m.Y';
}
```

The popup sub-module uses the value set here, but not as-is. The thing is that the date format used by the jquery popup is different than that set in #date_format. The date_popup sub-module automatically converts the date format with the functions "date_popup_format_to_popup" and "date_popup_format_to_popup_time".

Sorry that I didn't answer your question completely. I don't have time right now to  do that. But I hope you can get I gave you some insight that will help you for your specific problem. You may want to examine the functions 'date_popup_process_date_part' and 'date_popup_process_time_part' in the file 'date_popup/date_popup.module'

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module includes a 'Date Popup' sub-module which handles date pop-up widgets. These widgets are available in the FAPI (form api) and can be configured with custom formats via the `#date_format` property.

You could implement `hook_form_alter()` and change the `#date_format` property on the date field you're working with. I believe this property will support all formatting available in PHP's standard [date()](http://php.net/date) function.

Comment: When I do this in hook_form_alter() it just makes the date field's input box disappear.

Comment: `#date_format` is a weird one, you have to have it in exactly this format if I remember rightly: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: If there is a particular date format required to enter anything in `#date_format`, what is the point of having a `#date_format` element?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the [Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/scheduler) block options that have to be changed site-wide, the format can be set on the Scheduler settings page (http://example.com/admin/settings/scheduler)